# Не корректный ввод текста в WebView

Tags: java, android-studio, android-webview

Приложение грузит страницу с сайта в WebView ,на сайте нужно вводить данные в строках. При вводе текста я не вижу что ввожу ,только после дополнительного касания по сенсору показывается текст который я вводил. В чём может быть проблема? Я хотел бы видеть что ввожу в текстовое поле в реальном времени.
Вот обзор кода:

```
`@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.browser);
    final TextView txtview = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tV1);
    final ProgressBar pbar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.pB1);
    mWebview  = (WebView) findViewById(webView);
    WebSettings webSettings = mWebview.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    WebView mWebview = findViewById(R.id.webView);
    mWebview.getSettings().getJavaScriptEnabled();
    webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
    webSettings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    webSettings.setAllowFileAccess(true);
    webSettings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
      webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
     webSettings.setSupportZoom(true);
    webSettings.setAllowContentAccess(true);
    final Activity activity = this;
    mWebview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
            Toast.makeText(activity, description, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    mWebview .loadUrl("http://.............../");`
```